# How to use findPreference outside of PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to gain access to a (custom) list preference and change its selected value (i.e. if index 3 is selected, change the selection to index 1). However, findPreference() can only be used inside a PreferenceActivity. I need to access the preference and change its selection inside a regular Activity. Is there a way this can be done? I don't see anything in SharedPreferences that I can use to change the selection, only a list preferences value.

Comment: Ah, nm. sharedPref.edit().putString("pref","val").commit() actually changes it. I thought putString changed the backed array value of the currently selected item.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(this);
prefs.getString(PREF_KEY, "default");
```